# boost::array<char, 2> how to pass the 2 as variable

Tags: c++, boost

i am using a boost::array which has the format
< char, const std::size_t >

```
void test(const std::size_t XXX)
{
    boost::shared_ptr<boost::array<unsigned char, XXX>> buf(new boost::array<unsigned char, max_size>);
    .
    .
    .
};
test(100);
test(20);
```

This is leading

to the Error:

> error C2971: 'boost::array' : template parameter 'N' : 'size' : a local variable cannot be used as a non-type argument

Can you give me a hint how to pass boost::array the second parameter?

thanks

Comment: Why not use [`boost::shared_array<unsigned char>`](http://www.boost.org/libs/smart_ptr/shared_array.htm) instead?

Comment: Or for that matter `vector<unsigned char>` - by the looks of the code, I'd guess that `buf` is not intended to outlive the call to `test`, so shared ownership isn't needed. The only way it would be is if `test` stores it to some long-lived object (like a global, or `this` if `test` is a member function).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Templates are instantiated during the compilation, so that their parameters have to be known before the program runs.

That means you cannot use a variable as a template parameter. Such a parameters must be constant expressions (constant variables is not enough), addresses of functions or objects with external linkage, or addresses of static class members.

Answer (score 3):

The second parameter must be a compile time constant.

You could make `test()` a template function:

```
template <size_t max_size> void test()
{
    boost::shared_ptr<boost::array<unsigned char, max_size>> buf(
        new boost::array<unsigned char, max_size>);
}
test<100>();
test<20>();
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use a non-compile time value as a template parameter, since templates must be instantiated at compile time.

std::array and boost::array can only be used for statically sized arrays. If you need a dynamically sized array you can use std::vector instead.

And typically you don't need to hold onto a vector with a shared_ptr, just hold it directly:

```
void test(const std::size_t XXX)
{
    std::vector<char> buf(XXX);
    .
    .
    .
};
test(100);
test(20);
```

---

or like hmjd says you can pass XXX a compile time constant.

Answer (score 0):

Template value must be compile-time constant, that is literal, `constexpr` or `static const` variable.

Comment: Actually it can be, for example, statically initialized const int.

Comment: constant expression would be more appropriate than "runtime variable".  Of course, if something is statically initialized and constant... is it really a "variable"?

Comment: Per your edit, constant expression covers the other two cases.